# New comments not being returned in API feed

Tags: youtube-api

YouTube rolled out a new Google+ comment system. In the announcement [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments) they say that replies will not be returned in api feed, but suggest initial comments will be.  In my testing I've found that initial comments don't show up either.

YouTube please clarify this.  thanks

```
Replies to new-style YouTube comments via the YouTube and Google+ sites and apps will not be returned with the legacy API's comments feed. However, they will be available via the Google+ APIs.
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a YT GData API v2 call to retrieve comments which isn't returning what you expect? Be sure to make it clear what's missing from the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the .net client we use was ignoring the new comments.  Updating to the "beta" dlls fixed the problem.

Comment: As @Jeff Posnick says, can you provide corresponding v2 request?